# Клас User отказывается выводить Name (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

```
    @Bot.command(pass_context= True)
    async def info(ctx):
        emb = discord.Embed()
        emb.colour= 0x39d0d6
        emb.add_field(name= "Имя", value= discord.User.name)
        await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

Ошибка:

> Class 'User' has no 'name' member

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот эту запись

```py
discord.User.name
```

Отсылает интерпретатор не к `name` конкретного пользователя, а к статической переменной `name` класса `User` модуля `discord`, а этой переменной там нет, и никогда не было.
В данной ситуации логично использовать конструкцию

```
request.User.name
```

(или, если я правильно понял, в вашем случае `ctx.User.name`. Прошу поправить, если это не так)
О том, что такое статические переменные, можно почитать [здесь](http://csharpcoderr.com/1640/osnovy-staticheskih-metodov-i-peremennyh-java/). Тут это описано на примере Java, но для понимания того, что это вообще такое, этого будет достаточно.

Answer (score 0):

`discord.User.name` User в данном случае это просто класс(не объект)

В вашем случае нужно - `ctx.author.name`